# Symfony2 - Dynamically modify form using user inputs

Tags: symfony

A little bit of background first. I learned in the past how to use "pure" php, and have more recently started using Symfony. I have been following several guides (Cookbook, Lynda & Openclassrooms) for many of my inquiries, but I haven't been able to find an answer for my current question.

I have two entities, let's name them User and Player. The User entity contains a Player property which can be null.

So, during a User creation, I would like 3 possibilities : leave the Player field empty, select an already-existing player, or create a new Player. At first I wanted to add a "Create new" option in the Player dropdown list, but have simply gone for a "Create new Player" checkbox.

The idea is, if the checkbox is checked, I would like to remove the Player dropdown list and add an embedded form to create a new Player. I have tried several events (PRE_SET_DATA, PRE_SUBMIT & co), but none seem to trigger according to a user input.

This is something that I would have done in JScript, but seeing how Symfony's a much different animal than pure php, I don't know how to do it. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track there with `PRE_SET_DATA` and `PRE_SUBMIT` events.

You need to use JavaScript to reload form from server and Symfony form events to rebuild the form.

This is the documentation you're looking for: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Unfortunately, Symfony's form component is pretty complicated, so there are no simple code examples you can just take and use it without going through this article.

Also reading [Form Events documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html) is helpful for deeper understanding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I remember reading that part, but I skipped it because I did not (and still do not) understand the point of subscribing to both the PRE_SET_DATA and PRE_SUBMIT events.